# So, how is curSongJson not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does it say that curSongJson is not defined if I'm defining it in the displaySongs function when I run the application? I had it working before by removing the displaySongs function and just using a while loop but I need the function for tkinter and updating the label.

```
import requests
import time
import tkinter

token = ''
endpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing"
spotifyHeaders = {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token}
requestAmount = 1
#window = tkinter.Tk()
# imageLabel = tkinter.Label(window)
# imageLabel.pack()

def GrabSpotifyCurSong():
    return curSongJson['item']['name']
def GrabSpotifyCurArtist():
    return curSongJson['item']['artists'][0]['name']
def GrabCurrentSongImage():
    return curSongJson['item']['album']['images'][0]['url']
    
def displaySongs():
    try:
        curSong = requests.get(endpoint, headers=spotifyHeaders)
        curSongJson = curSong.json()
    except:
        print("Please start listening to a song")
        time.sleep(2)
    # with open('CurrentSong.jpg','wb+') as SongImage:
    # response = requests.get(GrabCurrentSongImage())
    # SongImage.write(response.content)
    currentSong = GrabSpotifyCurSong()
    currentArtist = GrabSpotifyCurArtist()
    # imageLabel['text'] = f'{currentArtist} - {currentSong}'
    print(f'{currentArtist} - {currentSong}')
    #     window.after(4000,displaySongs)

displaySongs()
# window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't get defined if there's an exception in your `try` block in `displaySongs` also you need to pass it as a parameter to your functions because it is not in their scopes

Comment: I put the try block in a while loop and now it works like that and I passed the cursongJson as a parameter and everything works. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `curSongJson` is a local variable so it's scope is limited to the function where it is defined. So, it will not be accessible outside the `displaySongs()` method.

You can pass the `currSongJson` to other functions as parameters where needed like -

```py
import requests
import time
import tkinter

token = ''
endpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing"
spotifyHeaders = {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token}
requestAmount = 1
#window = tkinter.Tk()
# imageLabel = tkinter.Label(window)
# imageLabel.pack()

def GrabSpotifyCurSong(curSongJson):
    return curSongJson['item']['name']
def GrabSpotifyCurArtist(curSongJson):
    return curSongJson['item']['artists'][0]['name']
def GrabCurrentSongImage(curSongJson):
    return curSongJson['item']['album']['images'][0]['url']
    
def displaySongs():
    try:
        curSong = requests.get(endpoint, headers=spotifyHeaders)
        curSongJson = curSong.json()
    except:
        print("Please start listening to a song")
        time.sleep(2)
    # with open('CurrentSong.jpg','wb+') as SongImage:
    # response = requests.get(GrabCurrentSongImage(curSongJson))
    # SongImage.write(response.content)
    currentSong = GrabSpotifyCurSong(curSongJson)
    currentArtist = GrabSpotifyCurArtist(curSongJson)
    # imageLabel['text'] = f'{currentArtist} - {currentSong}'
    print(f'{currentArtist} - {currentSong}')
    #     window.after(4000,displaySongs)

displaySongs()
# window.mainloop()
```